# How is this circular pattern of a streetlantarn behind a tree formed?

Tags: optics, reflection

A few months ago, while walking the dog at night, I noticed a strange effect. The streetlight shining behind a barren winter tree, was somehow changed, by reflection from the branches, showed a circular kind of pattern. As hopefully can seen below in the rather unsharp picture I took. The branche directions are randomly distributed. How is the circular pattern formed? I noticed it too on a dirty window on which the sun shone.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The branches may be randomly oriented, but the light is only strongly reflected perpendicular to the direction of the branch.  Those branches that point more or less toward the lamp (from your viewpoint) are not seen well.  Those branches that have a normal pointing toward the light are lit more.

For the branches that have a normal pointing toward the lamp, each will lie tangent to a circle centered at the lamp.  If there are enough, your eye might fill in the gaps and see them as tracing some of those circles.